# Matlab separate output into 2 variables

Tags: matlab, output

I have two float variables:

```
x = 0.5;
y = 1.5;
```

I would like to floor them:

```
x = floor(x);
y = floor(y);
```

Can i do it in a single command? this raises an error:

```
[x y] = floor([x y]);
```

Comment: Why is it you "need" the two variables separately?

Comment: Nothing really in particular... but this is a general question that can be applied to another usage. Don't focus on x, y

Comment: Then why not use `z = floor([x y])`? It's bound to be faster than @H.Muster's solution...If you must, just do `x = z(:,1), y = z(:,2)` at some point.

Comment: Like @RodyOldenhuis, I would also prefer the clean `floor` version over the wrapper I posted below to answer what the OP specifically asked for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper for floor:

```
function varargout = myFloor(varargin)
for k = 1:nargin
    varargout{k} = floor(varargin{k});
end
```

This function shows the required behavior if you provide x and y as two separated arguments

```
[a, b] = myFloor(x,y)
```

This results in

```
a =

     0


b =

     1
```

If you want to use the concatenated array `[x y]` as input (like in your example) you can use the following function:

```
function varargout = myFloor(x)
for k = 1:numel(x)
    varargout{k} = floor(x(k));
end
```

Then you would call

```
[a, b] = myFloor([x y])
```

This results in

```
a =

     0


b =

     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a random idea here...

Building on H.Muster solution, you might want to define a personalized `deal` function, which is like `deal` but also applies a function to each argument:

```
function varargout = myDeal(fun, varargin)
    if nargin == 2
        varargout(1:nargout) = {feval(fun, varargin{1})};
    elseif nargin-1 == nargout
        for k = 1:nargout
            varargout{k} = feval(fun, varargin{k}); end
    else
        error('Argument count mismatch.');
    end
end
```

This way, you can multi-assign *any* function:

```
>> [x,y,z] = myDeal(@floor, 0.5, 0.6, 2.7)
x =
     0
y =
     0
z =
     2

>>  [x,y,z] = myDeal(@sin, pi/6)
x =
     4.999999999999999e-01
y =
     4.999999999999999e-01
z =
     4.999999999999999e-01

>> [a, b] = myDeal(@fix, 10*rand(2), 8*rand(5))         
a =
     7     2
     7     6
b =
     5     2     4     1     6
     1     4     5     1     1
     0     1     7     2     7
     3     6     7     6     2
     7     2     4     2     1
```

Comment: @yes123: It will not be fast, at least, not as fast as doing things the vectorized way. Therefore I'd advise against using this in any "production code" or in performance-sensitive areas.

Comment: @yes123: a similar idea can be found in the function `disperse` [on the File Exchange](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/03/02/when-deal-doesnt-work-disperse-2/)

Comment: @Jonas: yes, I thought as much...truly new ideas are rare :)

Comment: @Jonas: Ah! But `disperse` doesn't pass things through functions, like the one above! :)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.
     Floor can only accept one argument as it can be seen from the syntax. You can see the reference below to verify:

http://www.mathworks.in/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/floor.html

Answer (score 0):

if

```
    A = [0.5 1.5]
```

then you can do

```
    floor(A)
```

that would result in

```
    ans = [0 1]
```

Here's an example: http://www.matlabtutorials.com/functions/floor.html

Comment: I need the results to be in the x and y var in a single command if it's possible

Comment: Then the answer is no. As Fyre said, floor() can only take one argument, which can in fact be a vector, but it will return a vector back.